# Plot[f,{x, xmin, xmax}], where xmax is not a const

Tags: programming, dynamic, plot-themes

[image: graph with constant 0 after some x]

I have a graph of the function, as in the picture.
Function can be set manually, but after a certain value, it is 0.
Could I  find this value to put it instead of xmax=1 in Plot in order to avoid useless tail f = 0 and make picture more readable?

The code

```
Show
[ 
ListPlot[Qp], PlotRange -> All,AxesLabel ->{"p,cars/m","Q,cars/s"}],
Plot[
   {f[p]},
   {p, 0, 1},
   AxesLabel -> {"p, cars/m", ""}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}
    ], 
ImageSize -> plotWidth
],
```

P.S.

```
 Qp = Transpose@{p, Q};
```

where Q and p are arrays

P.SS.
f[p] i get from InputField

Comment: the `0.7` is explicitly in your expression, why don't you just use it?

Comment: This value of the function can be changed manually.
After this immediately and dynamically changing  the graph.
Could you tell me,please, what can be done to change not only the graph, but also the scale

Comment: Have you tried using `Dynamic` to update the plot when the function is updated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may wish to consider a post-processing method.  You would need to make sure that the starting value is enough to include at least the range you wish to plot, but you can trim the zero area with this:

```
fixit = Show[
    MapAt[# /. Line[d_] :> Line[Join @@ Most @ SplitBy[d, Last@# == 0 &]] &, #, 1], 
    PlotRange -> Automatic] &;
```

For example:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x]*UnitBox[x/10], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

```
p // fixit
```

[image]

---

To include the line segment that drops to zero you may use this modified function:

```
fixit2 = Show[
    MapAt[# /. Line[d_] :> 
        Line[Join @@ MapAt[{First@#} &, SplitBy[d, Last@# == 0 &], -1]] &, #, 1], 
    PlotRange -> Automatic] &;
```

Test:

```
p // fixit2
```

[image]

Comment: very nice,thanks a lot. now i have something like
     http://pastebin.com/u5TNGDHS  
but after i change the function, the graph doesn't change dynamically.it is possible to do somethong with it?

Comment: f[x_] :> If[p < 0.05, -6044p^3 + 231p^2 + 22.2222p, If[p < 0.09, -3755p^3 + 767p^2 - 48p + 1.91376, If[p <= 0.7, 1.672 (0.7 -p), 0]]] imgur.com/EOKZ3b0 imgur.com/urySEMq i change the value in last "if" p <= 0.7 from 0.7 to 0.6 or 0.3 and,as you can see, not only zero area trimmed. Did you mean it when sad "You would need to make sure that the starting value is enough to include at least the range you wish to plot"?

Comment: @Mishin By the way I think your function should be: `f[p_] := If[p < 0.05, -6044 p^3 + 231 p^2 + 22.2222 p, 
  If[p < 0.09, -3755 p^3 + 767 p^2 - 48 p + 1.91376, If[p <= 0.7, 1.672 (0.7 - p), 0]]]`.  My function appears to be working as I intended on your example.  When you change the values as described you create an abrupt fall to zero, and my method does not include that "fall" as it were, just the point immediately before it.  I presume you would like to include that last vertical line dropping to zero?  I can do that I believe.

Answer (score 8):

### Random test function

I'm assuming all the functions to be considered are nonnegative, just as in the example.

```
SeedRandom[0];
data = Transpose[{
    Range[0., 1., 1./40],
    FoldList[
     Max[0., Min[##]] &,
     Reverse@Sort@RandomReal[{-0.65, 1}, {41}]
     ]
    }];
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### First Method

Use `EvaluationMonitor` to find where the function hits zero:

```
Module[{plot, zerox},
 {plot, zerox} = 
  Reap[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> If[f[x] == 0, Sow[x]]]];
 Show[plot, PlotRange -> {{0, Min[zerox]}, PlotRange[plot][[2]]}]
 ]
```

Or where it stops being zero:

```
Module[{plot, nonzerox},
 {plot, nonzerox} = 
  Reap[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> If[f[x] > 0, Sow[x]]]];
 Show[plot, PlotRange -> {{0, Max[nonzerox]}, PlotRange[plot][[2]]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Second Method

This resembles how one might think `Plot` would work: *drawing the line from one end until it is time to stop.*  Here we interpolate the test function with `NDSolve`, using [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html) to stop the process when the function hits zero.

```
ListLinePlot@NDSolveValue[
  {y[t] == f[t], x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0,
   WhenEvent[y[t] < 0, "StopIntegration"]},
  y, {t, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks a lot. totally my fault, using both methods I encounter a problem how and where should i put ListPlot[Qp] to display it also. Could you give me any advice please.

Comment: Would the graph changed dynamically after i will change the function in inputfield?

Comment: @MishinV. You included a `Manipulate` image, but not code for it.  It is not hard to make it work with `Manipulate` so that the plot updates dynamically, but, judging from other users' code on this site, the details of **how to do it well** depends on the code of each user.  A simple example might or might not be helpful to you.  What do you think?

Comment: I'm sorry, You are completely right. I'll try to deal with it on my own.

Comment: @MishinV.  You could ask another question about getting the plot to dynamically update with `Manipulate`.  (It's better than continually modifying this question, and better than trying to work it out in comments.)

Comment: I'll do this way. Thank You again. But still, what about putting ListPlot[Qp] in Your method to display both? I'm asking here, because this is Your unique answer, or should I also make a new question?

Comment: @MishinV. I don't see where you included the data for `Qp` -- or do you want just some random data and then `Show[ListPlot[Qp], plot,...]`?

Comment: "do you want just some random data" I hope, that would be enough to understand the logic and don't annoy You, how I included data for Qp. As You sad I asked another question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94309/listplot-dynamical-problems/ here there is some more information

Comment: Very nice methods! +1

Answer (score 3):

Not very robust ...

```
Panel[DynamicModule[{f = 1 - x^2 }, 
      Column[{InputField[Dynamic[f]], 
              Dynamic[Plot[ f, {x, 0, x /. Quiet@Last@Maximize[{x, f > 0}, x]}]]}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[{f[p]}, {p, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"p, cars/m", ""}, PlotRange -> 
{{0, Evaluate[x /. FindRoot[f[x] == 0, {x, .1}]]}, {0, Automatic}}]
```

[image]